# FFMPEG: How to keep UDP stream connection open even source drop some minute

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, vlc, dvb

i decode **UDP** stream (that genrate from DVB signal) using **ffmpeg** to **HLS** with this code :

```
ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 5 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

Sometime **DVB** signal drop for some second or minute and that lead to ffmpeg stop encoding and show error :

```
udp://239.1.2.1:60001: Connection timed out
```

When i play udp in VLC player and input stream drop for some second VLC wait stop play and when stream start again play again.

Now i want to know is there exist a way that ffmpeg either found that stream stop and dont show timeout error...it mean that FFMPEG keep connection open and wait for receive stream every time start from source. Thanks

Comment: add `-timeout <microseconds>` before `-i`

Comment: do you know what happened for output stream until timeout time?

Comment: as ffmpeg doc timeout use for RTSP input , you mean that it use for UDP too? https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

Comment: UDP has it too: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp

Comment: please post it as answer of question

Comment: RTP dont have that option, do you have idea for RTP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For UDP streams you can set timeout like:

```
ffmpeg -timeout 2000 -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000000
```

For RTP steams you can set timeout like:

```
ffmpeg -timeout 2000 -i rtp://192.168.0.12:1234
```

For RTSP streams you can specify timeouts in the SDP file

Comment: fifo_size dont need in RTP?

Comment: if you need some buffering add fifo_size else don't.

Comment: For RTP I get the error `Option timeout not found.` (`ffmpeg version 4.4`)

Comment: Isn't the `timeout` in microseconds. So this would equal to only 2 milliseconds?